# How to read PRS / SKmapDat files?

Tags: c++, python, c, perl, file-format

I have [these](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6sw6hjRojIVYWQwZjBkNTUtYjdmYi00ODVhLTk4YjUtM2YxN2FiNDJlYTM1&hl=en_US) graphic files from Legend of Mana, that I would like to understand how works.

```
  size  file name
149968  TWR_I100.IMG
 35500  TWR_RA00.IMG
148736  WAL_TMPL.PRS
214574  WAL_VLLG.PRS
 63762  WM_D351.PIM
  1208  WM_D352.DAT
 63446  WM_D352.PIM
  1208  WM_D353.DAT
```

The problem is figuring out how the pixels are stored.

The PRS files contains the string `SKmapDat` in the header.

I am pretty sure the `DAT` files are colour palettes.

Are there anyone in here, that have seen these type of files before and therefore knows how to read them?

Comment: these appear to be gamesaves, why don't you mention where the files come from? (_"You smell like a Jumi..."_ nice quote)

Comment: Is it ['聖剣伝説 LEGEND OF MANA' for PlayStation?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_Mana)

Comment: @sehe : Wow! You really know your stuff! Do you know why these formats were chosen for so many PS1 games?

Answer (score 2):

Game consoles have limited library/runtime support. Most often the formats are chosen to perform well on their hardware or to optimize storage. Have a look at http://www.zophar.net/utilities/psxutil.html for some resources that might help you

Comment: I found PSicture there, which could read the `TIM` files, which was used for all animations. From what I can tell, `TIM` files are pretty much `BMP` files. Sadly none of his utilities can read the mentioned files. Thanks though :)